# After installing Ubuntu how do I know that all devices have their necessary drivers

Tags: drivers

In Windows after a fresh install I go to the device manager to find out which devices have yellow question mark on them ie driver is missing

what about Ubuntu? sometimes you cant even tell that the driver is missing cause the device function is not visible like co-processor or something like that

In Windows you can find out about similar devices using the device manager

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04...

Comment: Anyway to do what I am asking about using the command line?

Comment: "some" ... exactly .. how do I list "All"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T

use this commands

```
lspci
lsusb
```

They will give a detailed report.

This command also can be used to list all devices to a file on your desktop.

```
sudo lshw -html >Desktop/myconfig.htm
```

Comment: ALL devices? is everything either pci or usb? no other bus? also how do I know if the driver is missing or its there?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu Linux, and GNU/Linux in general, we often just check for the desired result functionality instead of checking that "all necessary drivers were loaded".

In other words...

- if you want to test sound, try playing a music file or a YouTube video.
- if you want to test graphics, try playing a 3D game or press Super (Windows key) + W rapidly.
- if you want to test your mouse, move your mouse around and press the buttons.
- if you want to test your keyboard, type on your keyboard.
- if you want to test your webcam, try the free program "cheese"